# Employee Communities

Tags: lightning, community, partner-communities, employee-community

I have several questions:

1. Can non-Salesforce users be members of the Employee Community?
2. Can those users create and edit cases?
3. Can those users create and edit tasks on Contacts?

I'd like to use this for a number of part time workers who don't need to access everything in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

1. Non-internal users cannot be part of Employee Communities. These are meant for the old "Salesforce Platform" users.
2. They can only create internal Cases. Last I checked, this was something product management was working on to restrict, but basically they should only be logging cases for things like IT tickets.
3. Yes.

You're basically creating Salesforce Platform users, so anything those users can do, these can do as well, with the addition of the internal cases access. These users are not meant to be help desk employees - they cannot work on customer-related cases.